# Octobercms problem with .csv import/export on repeater fields

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv, octobercms, import-from-csv

I have a *customer* table and model using some [repeater fields](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-repeater) for **phones**, **mails** and **addresses**.

I use Import Export behavior.

I get "*Array to string conversion*" error if I don't use *json_encode* to export data:

```
namespace MyCompany\MyPlugin\Models;

use Model;
use Backend\Models\ExportModel;
use MyCompany\MyPlugin\Models\Customer;

class ExportCustomer extends \Backend\Models\ExportModel {

public function exportData($columns, $sessionKey = null) {
    $customers = Customer::all();

    $customers->each(function($customer) use ($columns) {
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            if (is_array($customer->$column)) {
                $customer->$column = json_encode($customer->$column);
            }
            $customer->addVisible($column);
        }
    });

    return $customers->toArray();
    }

}
```

But this way the resulting .*csv* is useless to my customer needs (he needs to **manually edit it before uploading it** in order to populate the backend).

EDIT: The goal is to have a prefixed column for each repeater field, so that my customer can edit easily, this way ("contact" is the repeater field):

```
| id | business_name | contact_1_name | contact_1_email | contact_1_mobile | contact_2_name | contact_2_email | contact_2_mobile | contact_3_name | contact_3_email | contact_3_mobile | ...
```

The data in my "*contacts*" column are json_encoded, indeed:

```
[{"name":"Eric Lucas","surname":"Riddle","role":"Manager","phone":"+1 (989) 305-8603","cellphone":"+1 (298) 758-1686","email":"calyqev@mailinator.com","linkedin":"mylinkedin"}]
```

Nonetheless, if I edit it and try to import it via the ImportCustomers model, I fill all the json_encoded tables with escaped data and I can't retrieve it on my view. The other fields are displayed correctly.

```
class ImportCustomer extends \Backend\Models\ImportModel
{
    public $rules = [];

    public function importData($results, $sessionKey = null)    {

        foreach ($results as $row => $data) {

            try {
                $customer = new Customer;
                $customer->fill($data);
                $customer->save();

                $this->logCreated();
            }
            catch (\Exception $ex) {
                $this->logError($row, $ex->getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to manage repeater fields?

Comment: if you share what format your customer expecting from you, means normal row to csv row is fine. but for repeater fields how your customer is expecting format to be to edit them as well, format means csv

Comment: @HardikSatasiya Sure, I've edited my question, thanx. I need to have a column for each field in the repeater. I'm aware of the fact that some customers will have many empty columns but I need this format for the sake of simplicity (aka "customer usability").